# Is a number $n$ known, which is not squarefree, but a strong fermat-pseudoprime to base $2$ and $3$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

This might be a duplicate, nevertheless, I will ask the question :

Wieferich primes : A prime $p$ is a Wieferich prime, if $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$. The only known Wieferich primes are $1093$ and $3511$.

I only found $1093^2$ and $3511^2$ to be a strong fermat-pseudoprime to base $2$ and to be not squarefree. Those numbers are not strong fermat-pseudoprime to base $3$.

> Is there a natural number $n>1$ with the following properties ?
>
> - n is not squarefree
> - n is a strong fermat-pseudoprime to base $2$ and $3$
>
> Assuming, the only Wieferich primes are $1093$ and $3511$, can it be
> shown that a number with the desired property cannot exists ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and $k$ the order of $2$ modulo $p$. Then either $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$, or the order of $2$ modulo $p^2$ is $p \cdot k$. Thus if $n$ is an odd number that is not squarefree and a Fermat pseudoprime to base $2$, and $p^2\mid n$, since $\gcd(p,n-1) = 1$, it follows that $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$, so $p$ must be a Wieferich prime. The analogous argument works for base $3$, so if such an $n$ exists, there must exist a Wieferich prime such that also $3^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$. So assuming there are no further Wieferich primes, since $3^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$ for $p = 1093$ and $p = 3511$, such a number cannot exist.

Comment: How do we know $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ p^2\ )$ ?

Comment: Because otherwise, the order of $2$ modulo $p$ is a multiple of $p$, and hence cannot divide $n-1$.

Comment: I noticed that I didn't explicitly write that $n$ should be a Fermat pseudoprime (we need not even require it to be a strong Fermat pseudoprime). I took it from the question that we only look at such $n$.

Comment: It is weird that I did not find this property online : If $n$ is a fermat-pseudoprime to base $a$ and $p^2|n$, then $p$ is a Wieferich-prime to base $a$. Does anyone know a link ? @Daniel Fischer Do I understand right that you proved this ?

Comment: There really isn't much to prove. Consider the order $k$ of $a$ modulo $p^2$. It divides $\varphi(p^2) = (p-1)\cdot p$ by Euler-Fermat. If $n$ is a base-$a$ Fermat pseudoprime, we also have $k \mid (n-1)$. Since $p \nmid (n-1)$, it follows that $k \mid \gcd(n-1,(p-1)p) = \gcd(n-1,p-1) \mid (p-1)$.

Comment: And this also works for higher prime powers because of $\phi(p^n)=p^{n-1}(p-1)$ , right ?

Comment: Right. So a Fermat pseudoprime is very likely squarefree. If it's a Fermat pseudoprime to several bases, even more likely. I don't know how rare base-$a$ Wieferich primes are for general $a$, but extrapolating from the rarity of base-$2$ Wieferich primes, they should be quite rare.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I wonder why I did not find this fact online.